# Chart.js - Thousand separator, currency in tool-tips, X & Y Axes labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I'm new to Chart.js and I've been trying to get all the snippets I've found to work together to get my labels and tool-tips to display correctly. I thought I would post my working script to show how I managed to get my values displayed with the thousand separator, a currency symbol added to the tool-tips and to the scales, and to have labels on the X and Y axes. Some of the posts I saw didn't have examples on where to place the relevant code.

Please note, I did not write all this code. This has been compiled from multiple Stack searches and multiple attempts to get some of it to work together.

Comment: So, what is exactly your problem?

Comment: I didn't say I had a problem... I'm just posting my working code to help other people who are new to Chart.js and Javascript.

Comment: Thanks @Rayza. Appreciate it bro.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the code I used...

```
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
               <script>
               var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
               var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                   type: 'bar',
                   data: {
                       labels: ["July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
                       datasets: [{
                           label: 'YTD 2017/18',
                           data: ["12000, 11250, 10000, 2000, 3000, 6000,12000, 11250, 10000, 2000, 3000, 6000"],
                           backgroundColor: [
                               'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                               'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                               'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                               'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                               'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                               'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                               'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                               'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                               'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                               'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                               'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                               'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                           ],
                           borderColor: [
                               'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                               'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                               'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                               'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                               'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                               'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                               'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                               'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                               'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                               'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                               'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                               'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                           ],
                           borderWidth: 1
                       }]
                   },
                   options: {
                       scales: {
                           yAxes: [{
                               scaleLabel: {
                                   display: true,
                                   labelString: 'Total Sales',
                                   fontStyle: 'bold',
                                   fontSize: 20
                               },
                              ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                  if(parseInt(value) >= 1000){
                                    return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                                  } else {
                                    return '$' + value;
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                          }],
                          xAxes: [{
                              scaleLabel: {
                                  display: true,
                                  labelString: 'Months of the Year',
                                  fontStyle: 'bold',
                                  fontSize: 20
                              }
                          }],
                       },
                       tooltips: {
                           callbacks: {
                             // this callback is used to create the tooltip label
                             label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                               // get the data label and data value to display
                               // convert the data value to local string so it uses a comma seperated number
                               var dataLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                               // add the currency symbol $ to the label
                               var value = ': $ ' + data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index].toLocaleString();
                               // make sure this isn't a multi-line label (e.g. [["label 1 - line 1, "line 2, ], [etc...]])
                               if (Chart.helpers.isArray(dataLabel)) {
                                 // show value on first line of multiline label
                                 // need to clone because we are changing the value
                                 dataLabel = dataLabel.slice();
                                 dataLabel[0] += value;
                               } else {
                                 dataLabel += value;
                               }
                               // return the text to display on the tooltip
                               return dataLabel;
                             }
                           }
                       },
                   }
               });
               </script>
```